# Get Only One Div (By Class) in WebView via JSoup

Tags: android, webview, jsoup

I am trying to get only one div (by class) to my webview. I don't know anything about PHP or CSS so i can't realize what should I do when i parse them by class name. I want to take 
    `<div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color fullsize">`
part here but its so complicated so i really don't know what to write on doc.select(div. "HERE"). Thanks in advice.

Divs I Must Parse:

```
<div id="wrap_all">
    <div class="mobil-logo">    
    <div id="main" data-scroll-offset="88"> 
<!--- header icerik sonu--->
        <div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color fullsize">
            <div class="container">
```

And this is what I tried in Main.java:

```
// webview settings here
loadJsoup();

 public void loadJsoup(){
     try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://isvecehliyet.se/mobil").timeout(10000).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Element ele = doc.select("div.entry-content-wrapper").first(); 
        String html = ele.toString();
        String mime = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        mWebview.loadData(html, mime, encoding);
 }
```

Comment: Whay you need in that Div? Image or Paragraph or heading? It's unclear.

Comment: @YuvaRaj, OP wants the **entire** div, so he can get the HTML which is in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
String url = "http://isvecehliyet.se/mobil/";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

Elements e = doc.select("div.container").first().parents();

System.out.println(e);
```

Part of output:

```
<div class="container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color fullsize"> 
 <div class="container"> 
  <main class="template-page content  av-content-full alpha units" role="main" itemprop="mainContentOfPage"> 
   <article class="post-entry post-entry [...]
```